# How to store something in JavaScript temporarily?

Tags: javascript, storage

I am trying to create blackjack with JS and React. 
So far I have got most of it working but my main problem is that everytime react renders it changes the cards and the order of the deck etc. I just need a simple way to store data and so even when react re renders it keeps the order of the deck (array of objects). I am use to firebase but that seems quite heavy for something like this. any ideas? i saw local storage might be an option too but wanted peoples opinions.

Comment: Quite a lot of the examples and tutorials on the React website are about state management. If the components are resetting when being re-rendered, the problem is in your state management code. You don't need to store the info elsewhere (unless you want it to survive a page refresh).

Comment: Every time react renders? Does that involve a physical page reload? If not then you are using react wrong (and if yes then you are most likely using it wrong, too). Show your code. Create a runnable example that reproduces your issue. All the tools are there.